# Как отобразить bytearray

Tags: java, android

Делаю post запрос для отладки приложения, в ответ получаю bytearray как его отобразить хоть где-нибудь?
Если я пытаюсь отобразить его в textview то у меня получается краш.

```
String myURL = "http://s92640jz.bget.ru/register.php";
        String params = "login=user123&open_key=rgh24sfs3efs234dir&key_size=4096";
        byte[] data = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            data = params.getBytes("UTF-8");
            os.write(data);
            data = null;

            conn.connect();
            int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Такого вот размера буфер
            // Далее, например, вот так читаем ответ
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            data = baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null)
                    is.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Метод Arrays.toString() вернет `String` представление массива

```
byte[] b1 = new byte[] {97, 98, 99};

String s1 = Arrays.toString(b1);
String s2 = new String(b1);

Log.v("MYLOG", s1);        // -> "[97, 98, 99]"
Log.v("MYLOG", s2);        // -> "abc";
```

Comment: Не выходит так вот такой краш получаю:k.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)

Comment: Использую так: Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), new String(data));

Comment: Скиньте полный лог ошибки.

Comment: Подозреваю что у Вас NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с

> Подозреваю что у Вас NullPointerException - Владимир Seos-Lab

```
Log.v("new String() = ", new String(data));
```